# how to use router in spring integration?

Tags: spring, ftp, spring-integration

I use `router` in Spring Integration project, I want to route message based on custom expression, for this reason, I defined a router and two channels for route messages, my router code is:

```
<int:router input-channel="toSplitter"
                default-output-channel="aggregateResultsChannel"
                expression="@util.determine(payload)"
            >
        <int:mapping value="true" channel="mvChannel" />
        <int:mapping value="false" channel="toGet" />
    </int:router>
```

and in my bean :

```
public class util {
    public static boolean determine(List<FileInfo> path) {
        for(FileInfo fileInfo:path) {
             evaluate(fileInfo);
         }
         return;//how to return here...
    }  
}
```

the problem is that I want evaluate each path object and route each message to different channel, for example the `list` contain `{file1,file2}` 
, then after evaluating file1 route to mvChannel and file2 route toGet chennel  how do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `<router>` can be configured even without any `<mapping>`. In this case the `route function` must return the `MessageChannel` bean name.

For example:

---

```
public class util {
    public static String determine(List<FileInfo> path) {
        return evaluate(path) ? "mvChannel" : "toGet";
    }  
}
```

Comment: thanks for reply @Artem and edit my post :) , i want to route each item of `path` List, for example:
`for(FileInfo fileInfo:path) {
    // how do it here
}`

Comment: For the `Collection` `payload` you must use `<splitter>` before `<router>`. Each EIP component is only responsible for its aim, nothing more. Be flexible and try to follow with `loosely-coupling` principle. Please, read http://www.enterpriseintegrationpatterns.com/ first of all.